# Design a multiple columns environment to arrange exercises

Tags: numbering, enumerate

I want write the code like:

```
...
    \item
    \textbf{Differentiation}.

    Differentiate with respect to $x$:
    \begin{exercises}{3}
        \item$x^{2} - 3x$.
        \item$x^{5} - \dfrac{x^3}{3}$.
        \item$x + \dfrac{1}{x}$.
        ...
    \end{exercises}

    \item
    Differentiate with respect to $x$:
        \begin{exercises}{2}
        \item$y = x\cos\frac{1}{2}x$.
        \item$y = \sin\left(\dfrac{\pi x}{180}\right)$.
        \item$y = \frac{x^2}{1+x}$.
        ...
        \end{exercises}
    ...
...
```

[image: sample pic]

But if I use `shortlst` package as an advice from [An environment which be used to arrange exercises mostly similiar with common enumerate list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34316/an-environment-which-be-used-to-arrange-exercises-mostly-similiar-with-common-en), the content after second `\item Differentiate with respect to $x$` in pic above will typeset in three columns.

----EDIT----
The proposal that use a `minipage` environment is restricted with the minipage's width defined in advance, that say, it is not suit for different page width. change

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shortlst}
\usepackage[width=10cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\newenvironment{exercises}[1]
    {#1:\\ \begin{minipage}[t]{0.9\textwidth}\begin{shortenumerate}}
    {\end{shortenumerate}\end{minipage}}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{exercises}{\textbf{Differentiation}\\ Differentiate with respect to $x$}
     \item $x^3-3x$
     \item $x^5-\frac{x^3}{3}$
     \item $x+\frac{1}{x}$
     \item $(x+1)^2(x-1)^2$
     \item $x\sin x$
\end{exercises}
\item
\begin{exercises}{Differentiate with respect to $x$}
     \item $y=x\cos \frac{1}{2}x$
     \item $y=\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)$
     \item $y=\frac{x^2}{1+x}$ 
\end{exercises}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shortlst}
\usepackage[width=9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\newenvironment{exercises}[1]
    {#1:\\ \begin{minipage}[t]{0.9\textwidth}\begin{shortenumerate}}
    {\end{shortenumerate}\end{minipage}}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{exercises}{\textbf{Differentiation}\\ Differentiate with respect to $x$}
     \item $x^3-3x$
     \item $x^5-\frac{x^3}{3}$
     \item $x+\frac{1}{x}$
     \item $(x+1)^2(x-1)^2$
     \item $x\sin x$
\end{exercises}
\item
\begin{exercises}{Differentiate with respect to $x$}
     \item $y=x\cos \frac{1}{2}x$
     \item $y=\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)$
     \item $y=\frac{x^2}{1+x}$ 
\end{exercises}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

will get

[image: sample2]

so is the code given by Schweinebacke unless I changed the width individually

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{shortlst}% http://ctan.org/pkg/shortlst 
\usepackage{scrextend} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[width=10cm]{geometry} %added
\begin{document} 

\lipsum[1] 
\begin{enumerate} 
\item {Differentiate with respect to $x$: 
  \begin{addmargin}[0pt]{0.1\linewidth} 
    \begin{shortenumerate} 
      \item $x^3-3x$  
      \item $x^5-\frac{x^3}{3}$ 
      \item $x+\frac{1}{x}$ 
      \item $(x+1)^2(x-1)^2$ 
      \item $x\sin x$ 
    \end{shortenumerate} 
  \end{addmargin} 
} 
\item {Differentiate with respect to $x$: 
  \begin{addmargin}[0pt]{.4\linewidth} 
    \begin{shortenumerate} 
      \item $y=x\cos \frac{1}{2}x$ 
      \item $y=\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)$ 
      \item $y=\frac{x^2}{1+x}$ 
      \item $y=x\cos \frac{1}{2}x$ 
      \item $y=\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)$ 
      \item $y=\frac{x^2}{1+x}$ 
      \item $y=x\cos \frac{1}{2}x$ 
      \item $y=\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)$ 
      \item $y=\frac{x^2}{1+x}$ 
      \item $y=x\cos \frac{1}{2}x$ 
      \item $y=\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)$ 
      \item $y=\frac{x^2}{1+x}$ 
    \end{shortenumerate} 
  \end{addmargin} 
} 
\end{enumerate} 
\end{document}
```

[image: sample3]

Comment: Have you considered the `multicol` package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of [your earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34316/an-environment-which-be-used-to-arrange-exercises-mostly-similiar-with-common-en), possibly in a minipage, and an ordinary enumeration environment should get the result you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shortlst}% http://ctan.org/pkg/shortlst
\begin{document}

\newenvironment{exercises}[1]
    {#1:\\ \begin{minipage}[t]{0.9\textwidth}\begin{shortenumerate}}
    {\end{shortenumerate}\end{minipage}}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\begin{exercises}{\textbf{Differentiation}\\ Differentiate with respect to $x$}
     \item $x^3-3x$ 
     \item $x^5-\frac{x^3}{3}$
     \item $x+\frac{1}{x}$
     \item $(x+1)^2(x-1)^2$
     \item $x\sin x$
\end{exercises}
\item 
\begin{exercises}{Differentiate with respect to $x$}
     \item $x^3-3x$ 
     \item $x^5-\frac{x^3}{3}$
     \item $x+\frac{1}{x}$
     \item $(x+1)^2(x-1)^2$
     \item $x\sin x$
\end{exercises}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

which looks like

[image]

If you want a table like environment to handle a specific number of columns of equations, then you can define a new counter to do this.

```
\newcounter{innerlist} 
\renewcommand{\theinnerlist}{\arabic{innerlist}} 
\newcommand{\inneritem}[1]{\refstepcounter{innerlist}\theinnerlist.\ #1}

\newenvironment{exercises}[2]
    {\setcounter{innerlist}{0}\begin{minipage}[t]{0.9\textwidth}#1:\\ \begin{tabular}{#2}}
    {\end{tabular}\end{minipage}}


\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \begin{exercises}{\textbf{Differentiation}\\ Differentiate with respect to $x$}{ll}
        \inneritem{$x^3-3x$} & \inneritem{$x^5-\frac{x^3}{3}$}\\
        \inneritem{$x+\frac{1}{x}$} & \inneritem{$(x+1)^2(x-1)^2$}\\
        \inneritem{$x\sin x$} & \inneritem{$x\sin x$}
    \end{exercises}
    \item
    \begin{exercises}{\textbf{Differentiation}\\ Differentiate with respect to $x$}{lll}
        \inneritem{$x^3-3x$} & \inneritem{$x^5-\frac{x^3}{3}$} & \inneritem{$x+\frac{1}{x}$}\\
        \inneritem{$(x+1)^2(x-1)^2$} & \inneritem{$x\sin x$} & \inneritem{$x\sin x$}
    \end{exercises}
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

This version shouldn't have any big issues spreading over pages. Each minipage  shouldn't spread between pages, but the items in the outer enumerated list will spread fine.

An alteration using the longtables package allows this to run over pages:

```
\newenvironment{exercises}[2]
    {\setcounter{innerlist}{0}#1:\\ \begin{longtable}[t]{#2}}
    {\end{longtable}}
```

Comment: Thank you. But a `minipage` environment can not break page down nicely.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you explain what is wrong with minipage? See the image I included above as an example.

Comment: Note that you must include `t` as an optional argument to minipage to get the numbers in the right place.

Comment: I mean if the quantity of items inside a minipage is too large, there will occur an overfull.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You can limit the horizontal size of a minipage. In this code I have to `0.9\textwidth`.

Comment: @Mark S. Everitt: I don't think that the horizontal size is the problem. But if there are a lot of items at the `shortenumerate`, a page break inside of the `shortenumerate` may be useful. But there cannot be any page break inside a `minipage`. Have a look at the example at my modified answer.

Comment: Hmm, sure, but this is fairly trivial. I don&t think that this is his problem. I think it's the number of items width in each question set.

Comment: At the bottom of my answer there is now something that allow you to set exercises like columns in a table. It's kinda overkill, but will work.

Comment: @Mark Thanks a lot. The problem is I have finished the formula like `item`'s grammar. It would be a boring business if I change the style of typewriting.

Comment: You're going to be hard pushed to get much better than this. What your asking for is very specific and tricky to code. Potentially, you could write a loop to fill elements using something like `item`, but the tedium of writing that will far outweigh the tedium of reorganising your code. Another option is to vary the number of columns as you go along, but then numbering will be hard...

Answer (score 3):

You could use a combination of `multicols` with a `newlist` using the `enumitem` package, as demonstrated below.

It allows pagebreaks too.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{multicol}             % multicols
\usepackage{enumitem}             % customized lists
\usepackage[width=10cm]{geometry} % page dimensions

% setup a new list (terminology from enumitem)
\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[mylist]{label=(\alph*)}

\newenvironment{exercises}[1]{\begin{multicols}{#1}\begin{mylist}}{\end{mylist}\end{multicols}}

\begin{document} 

\vspace*{4cm}   % purely to demonstrate the pagebreak
\lipsum[1-2] 

\begin{enumerate} 
 \item {Differentiate with respect to $x$:}
  \begin{exercises}{2}
      \item $x^3-3x$  
      \item $x^5-\frac{x^3}{3}$ 
      \item $x+\frac{1}{x}$ 
      \item $(x+1)^2(x-1)^2$ 
      \item $x\sin x$ 
  \end{exercises} 
 \item Differentiate with respect to $x$:
 \begin{exercises}{2}
      \item $y=x\cos \frac{1}{2}x$ 
      \item $y=\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)$ 
      \item $y=\frac{x^2}{1+x}$ 
      \item $y=x\cos \frac{1}{2}x$ 
      \item $y=\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)$ 
      \item $y=\frac{x^2}{1+x}$ 
      \item $y=x\cos \frac{1}{2}x$ 
      \item $y=\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)$ 
      \item $y=\frac{x^2}{1+x}$ 
      \item $y=x\cos \frac{1}{2}x$ 
      \item $y=\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)$ 
      \item $y=\frac{x^2}{1+x}$ 
  \end{exercises} 
\end{enumerate} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to combine Mark's answer with package [scrextend](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script). That would support page breaks inside the exercise:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shortlst}% http://ctan.org/pkg/shortlst
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{enumerate}
\item {Differentiate with respect to $x$:
  \begin{addmargin}[0pt]{2em}
    \begin{shortenumerate}
      \item $x^3-3x$ 
      \item $x^5-\frac{x^3}{3}$
      \item $x+\frac{1}{x}$
      \item $(x+1)^2(x-1)^2$
      \item $x\sin x$
    \end{shortenumerate}
  \end{addmargin}
}
\item {Differentiate with respect to $x$:
  \begin{addmargin}[0pt]{2em}
    \begin{shortenumerate}
      \item $y=x\cos \frac{1}{2}x$
      \item $y=\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)$
      \item $y=\frac{x^2}{1+x}$
      \item $y=x\cos \frac{1}{2}x$
      \item $y=\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)$
      \item $y=\frac{x^2}{1+x}$
      \item $y=x\cos \frac{1}{2}x$
      \item $y=\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)$
      \item $y=\frac{x^2}{1+x}$
      \item $y=x\cos \frac{1}{2}x$
      \item $y=\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)$
      \item $y=\frac{x^2}{1+x}$
    \end{shortenumerate}
  \end{addmargin}
}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Note: If you're already using a [KOMA-Script class](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) you don't need to load the package `scrextend`.

You may define an enviroment for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shortlst}% http://ctan.org/pkg/shortlst  
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{lipsum}% 
\usepackage[width=10cm]{geometry} %added

\newenvironment{exercise}[1][\strut]{%
  \item #1\begin{addmargin}[0pt]{2em}\begin{shortenumerate} 
}{%
  \end{shortenumerate}\end{addmargin} 
}
\begin{document} 

\lipsum[1] 
\begin{enumerate}
  \begin{exercise}[{Differentiate with respect to $x$:}]
  \item $x^3-3x$  
  \item $x^5-\frac{x^3}{3}$ 
  \item $x+\frac{1}{x}$ 
  \item $(x+1)^2(x-1)^2$ 
  \item $x\sin x$ 
  \end{exercise}
  \begin{exercise}[{Differentiate with respect to $x$:}]
  \item $y=x\cos \frac{1}{2}x$ 
  \item $y=\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)$ 
  \item $y=\frac{x^2}{1+x}$ 
  \item $y=x\cos \frac{1}{2}x$ 
  \item $y=\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)$ 
  \item $y=\frac{x^2}{1+x}$ 
  \item $y=x\cos \frac{1}{2}x$ 
  \item $y=\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)$ 
  \item $y=\frac{x^2}{1+x}$ 
  \item $y=x\cos \frac{1}{2}x$ 
  \item $y=\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)$ 
  \item $y=\frac{x^2}{1+x}$ 
  \end{exercise} 
\end{enumerate} 
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of both examples]

Comment: If I add `\usepackage[b5paper]{geometry}` I couldn't get a desired result.

Comment: @Tau spit: I get the desired result even if I add `\usepackage[b5paper]{geometry}` to my MWE. Page break would be earlier, but first has still three columns while second has two columns. Nevertheless you may simply change value `0.1\linewidth` and `0.4\linewidth` at the example to the value you need to get one, two or three columns as you like. BTW: IMHO b5paper is a strange paper width for a document. a5paper would be more common. In this case you may use `.3\linewidth` at the second exercise to get two columns.

Comment: Thanks for your explain. I have edited the question. The problem is I don't want change the width one by one.

Comment: @Tau spit: I still do not understand the problem. Why shouldn't the second exercise be set in three columns (that would be, if you simply remove `minipage` or `addmargin` from the suggested answers). If you just want little more right indention, just try my changed example with always 2em right indention and three columns for the first exercise but two for the second, without changing the width.

Comment: I just want my result's appearance is close to the origin document as far as possible. As for the origin doc, why shouldn't the second exercise be set in three columns? I don't know either. Maybe just for neat and tidy.

Comment: @Tauspit: Nothing says thank you like an up vote. That's the SE way.

Comment: @Tau spit: If you want to be as close at the original document as possible you won't be able to avoid manual adjustment. The only chance to avoid manual adjustment would be to use the same software environment including the same fonts, sizes and algorithms. So the differences in possible answers to your question may only be: what kind of manual adjustment may/should be used.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using the `{tasks}` environment provided by the [`exsheets`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets) package. There is at least one downside to it, though: it cannot safely be nested with other `{tasks}` environments. (It is not a real list in the LaTeX sense although the syntax is similar.)

The environment has an optional argument that specifies the number of columns:

```
\begin{tasks}{<num of cols>}
 \task first item
 \task second item
 ...
\end{tasks}
```

Here is the full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[load-headings]{exsheets}

\SetupExSheets{
  % first the number then the title:
  headings=block-rev,
  % number tasks (a), (b), ...
  tasks/label=(tsk[a]),
  % make sure the task item labels have enough space:
  tasks/label-width=2em
}
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text

\begin{document} 

\lipsum[1]\bigskip

\begin{question}[name=Differentiation]
 Differentiate with respect to $x$: 
 \begin{tasks}{3}% three columns
   \task $x^3-3x$  
   \task $x^5-\frac{x^3}{3}$ 
   \task $x+\frac{1}{x}$ 
   \task $(x+1)^2(x-1)^2$ 
   \task $x\sin x$
 \end{tasks}
\end{question}

\begin{question}[name=More Differentiation]
 Differentiate with respect to $x$: 
 \begin{tasks}{2}% two columns
   \task $y=x\cos \frac{1}{2}x$ 
   \task $y=\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)$ 
   \task $y=\frac{x^2}{1+x}$ 
   \task $y=x\cos \frac{1}{2}x$ 
   \task $y=\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)$ 
   \task $y=\frac{x^2}{1+x}$ 
   \task $y=x\cos \frac{1}{2}x$ 
   \task $y=\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)$ 
   \task $y=\frac{x^2}{1+x}$ 
   \task $y=x\cos \frac{1}{2}x$ 
   \task $y=\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)$ 
   \task $y=\frac{x^2}{1+x}$ 
 \end{tasks}
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]