# Several \begin{equation} \end{equation} in columns

Tags: tables, equations, columns

I have 3 elements of the following form (approx ~20 equations for each one) :

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
% LOTS OF EQUATIONS %
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

How to put display these 3 elements in 3 columns on one page ?

I tried :

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
% LOTS OF EQUATIONS %
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
&
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
% LOTS OF EQUATIONS %
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
&
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
% LOTS OF EQUATIONS %
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{tabular}
```

But it does not work and return the following error :

```
 You can't use '\eqno' in restricted horizontal mode
```

How to do what I want to do?

Comment: you should have a look at `alignedat` see [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#Other_environments)<br>
other solutions could involve `\usepackage{multicol}`, `\vfill` and `\columnbreak` see [here][2]<br>
and a third variant could use `minipage`<br>
and you should also have a look at [here][3] [2]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8683/how-do-i-force-a-column-break-in-a-multi-column-page
[3]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35460/design-a-multiple-columns-environment-to-arrange-exercises

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to hide the alignment operators of the [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) environments - `&` and `\\` - from `tabular`. Do this by grouping the content (placing it inside `{`...`}`). Here's a minimal example showing its use inside a [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) environment (it's just easier to spread it across the `\linewidth` equally this way):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}XXX@{}}
  {\begin{align}
    y&=17x  \\ y&=7x  \\ y&=12x  \\ y&=14x  \\ y&=1x  \\ y&=8x  \\ y&=9x  \\ y&=5x  \\ y&=11x  \\ y&=16x  \\
    y&=18x  \\ y&=3x  \\ y&=13x  \\ y&=4x  \\ y&=2x  \\ y&=15x  \\ y&=6x  \\ y&=19x  \\ y&=10x  \\ y&=20x
  \end{align}} &
  {\begin{align}
    y&=17x  \\ y&=7x  \\ y&=12x  \\ y&=14x  \\ y&=1x  \\ y&=8x  \\ y&=9x  \\ y&=5x  \\ y&=11x  \\ y&=16x  \\
    y&=18x  \\ y&=3x  \\ y&=13x  \\ y&=4x  \\ y&=2x  \\ y&=15x  \\ y&=6x  \\ y&=19x  \\ y&=10x  \\ y&=20x
  \end{align}} &
  {\begin{align}
    y&=17x  \\ y&=7x  \\ y&=12x  \\ y&=14x  \\ y&=1x  \\ y&=8x  \\ y&=9x  \\ y&=5x  \\ y&=11x  \\ y&=16x  \\
    y&=18x  \\ y&=3x  \\ y&=13x  \\ y&=4x  \\ y&=2x  \\ y&=15x  \\ y&=6x  \\ y&=19x  \\ y&=10x  \\ y&=20x
  \end{align}}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}​
```