# width of \parbox issue

Tags: spacing, macros, formatting, indentation

I am using a template for a CV in LaTeX and I am facing certian difficulties in getting things aligned properly.

The code I am referring to is

```
\newcommand{\NewEntry}[3]{% Define a command for each new block - change spacing and font sizes here: #1 is the left margin, #2 is the italic date field and #3 is the position/employer/location field
    \noindent\hangindent=0em\hangafter=0
    \parbox{\datebox}{\small\textit{#1}}
    \hspace{1em} #2 #3
    }
```

[image]

As you can see, "Feb'14--current" is getting displayed in two lines instead of one. Is there a way I can edit the `\newcommnad` instruction so that I can get the desired result, i.e in one single line.

Comment: It would be helpful to see a full working example.  But from what you've shown, `\datebox` would appear to be a width, which is too small to allow the text to fit.  You could increase the size of `\datebox`, you could replace its appearance in this macro by an explicitly larger length.  If neither of those options are available (for other reasons), you could replace `\textit{#1}` with `\makebox[0pt][l]{\textit{#1}}`, though this latter brute force approach runs the risk of overlap.

Comment: the bruteforce method worked for now. i still would like to kno how to increase the length of \datebox

Comment: `\setlength{\datebox}{<length>}`. Most likely you don't know how big the longest entry will be in the first place. So, first of all I would call the parbox with the optional parameter "t", like `\parbox[t]...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in my comment, it would be good to know more about the CV style.  But the problem is that the length `\datebox` is not sufficient to hold the string.  You can increase `\datebox`, or manually force the string to overrun the allocated space (at the risk of overlap).

The original size of `\datebox=.7in` was pulled out of thin air for this MWE, merely to show a size that doesn't work with the input data.  Your CV style would need to be consulted to determine the actual length allocated for it.

I also made the `\parbox` with the `[t]` option, so that any overrun, if allowed, would not change the vertical placement of the datebox text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength\datebox
\datebox=.7in\relax% OR PREFERABLY \setlength{\datebox}{0.7in}
\newcommand{\NewEntry}[3]{\noindent\hangindent=0em\hangafter=0 %
  \parbox[t]{\datebox}{\small\textit{#1}}\hspace{1em} #2 #3 }
\begin{document}
\parindent 0in\parskip 1ex
AS IS (approximately):

\NewEntry{Feb'14--current}{Technical Service Manager}{Blah}

INCREASING datebox:

\datebox=.9in
\NewEntry{Feb'14--current}{Technical Service Manager}{Blah}

BRUTE FORCE:

\datebox=.7in% RESTORE ORIGINAL
\renewcommand{\NewEntry}[3]{\noindent\hangindent=0em\hangafter=0 %
  \parbox[t]{\datebox}{\small\makebox[0pt][l]{\textit{#1}}}\hspace{1em} #2 #3 }
\NewEntry{Feb'14--current}{Technical Service Manager}{Blah}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: here is the template http://www.latextemplates.com/template/classicthesis-styled-cv for you perusal

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend to use this template anayway. But, your problem is solvable within the given setting: You need to set the `\datebox` width to your longest date caption. Assuming that this is the problematic "Feb'14--current" you would say

```
\settowidth{\datebox}{Feb'14--current}
```

[image]

In case you really want to use the template you should strongly consider to take over my adjustments (see the complete code below).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita}
  \renewcommand{\cvheadingfont}{\LARGE\color{Maroon}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
  \hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=Maroon,linkcolor=Maroon}

\reversemarginpar

\newlength{\datebox}
\settowidth{\datebox}{Feb'14--current}

\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedleft\itshape\small#1}}
\newcommand{\NewEntry}[3]{%
  \par\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0
  \parbox[t]{\datebox}{\small \textit{#1}}
  \hspace{1.5em} #2 #3
  \vspace{0.5em}
  \par}
\newcommand{\Description}[1]{%
  \par\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0
  {\raggedright\footnotesize #1\par}
  \vspace{1em}
  \par}

\begin{document}

\begin{cv}{\spacedallcaps{John Smith}}\vspace{1.5em} % Your name

\section*{Personal Information}

\NewEntry{}{\textit{Born in Canada,}}{20 November 1987} % Birthplace and date

\NewEntry{email}{\href{mailto:john@smith.com}{john@smith.com}} % Email address

\NewEntry{website}{\href{http://www.johnsmith.com}{http://www.johnsmith.com}} % Personal website

\NewEntry{phone}{(H) +1 (000) 111 1111\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ (M) +1 (000) 111 1112} % Phone number(s)

\vspace{1em} % Extra white space between the personal information section and goal


\section*{Goal}

\Description{Gain fundamental experience in my area of interest and expertise.}\vspace{2em}


\section*{Work Experience}

\NewEntry{2012--Present}{1\textsuperscript{st} Year Analyst, \textsc{Lehman Brothers}}

\Description{%
  \MarginText{Lehman Brothers}%
  Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a wide array of commodities (ags, oils, precious and base metals), managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes, liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping.
  \newline Reference: John \textsc{McDonald}\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ +1 (000) 111 1111\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \href{mailto:john@lehman.com}{john@lehman.com}}

\NewEntry{2010--2011}{Summer Intern, \textsc{Initech Inc}  --- Chicago}

\Description{%
  \MarginText{Initech Inc}%
  Rated "truly distinctive" for Analytical Skills and Teamwork.
  \newline Reference: Bill \textsc{Lumbergh}\ \ +1 (000) 111 1111\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \href{mailto:bill@initech.com}{bill@initech.com}}

\NewEntry{Feb'14--current}{Technical Service Manager, \textsc{Gilette, PnG}}

\Description{%
  \MarginText{Buy More}%
  Worked in the Nerd Herd and helped to solve computer problems by asking customers to turn their computers off and on again.
  \newline Reference: Big \textsc{Mike}\ \ +1 (000) 111 1111\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \href{mailto:mike@buymore.com}{mike@buymore.com}}

\end{cv}
\end{document}
```

<sub>**Note.** Changes to the template include hard-coding issues, e.g. replacing `\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{<heading text>}` with `\section*{<heading text>}`, misuse of the `\footnotesize` macro and a better handling of the spacing.</sub>

### Addendum

To be 100% sure that no "date-item" will clip with the border of its box, you could measure each item and set `\datebox` to the widest measured width *automatically*. There is an answer whose method could be applied to this question too:

[Maintaining structure Workbook style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149273/maintaining-structure-workbook-style/214547#214547)

An alternative approach is to check each item and to write the biggest value into the main auxiliary file, and retrieve this value at the beginning - which requires two compiling cycles to see actual changes:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita}
  \renewcommand{\cvheadingfont}{\LARGE\color{Maroon}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
  \hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=Maroon,linkcolor=Maroon}

\reversemarginpar

\newdimen\datebox
\newdimen\tempdima \tempdima0pt
\newdimen\maxdatedimen \maxdatedimen30pt%default value

\newcommand{\NewEntry}[3]{%
  \settowidth\tempdima{#1}%
  \ifdim\tempdima>\maxdatedimen%
    \global\maxdatedimen\the\tempdima\fi%
  \par\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0
  \parbox[t]{\datebox}{\small \textit{#1}}
  \hspace{1.5em} #2 #3
  \vspace{0.5em}
  \par}
\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedleft\itshape\small#1}}
\newcommand{\Description}[1]{%
  \par\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0
  {\raggedright\footnotesize #1\par}
  \vspace{1em}
  \par}

\usepackage{atveryend}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \settowidth{\datebox}{\hbox to \the\maxdatedimen{\hfil}}
  \maxdatedimen0pt}
\AfterLastShipout{%
  \if@filesw
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{%
      \global\string\maxdatedimen=\the\maxdatedimen\relax
    }%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{cv}{\spacedallcaps{John Smith}}\vspace{1.5em} % Your name

\section*{Personal Information}

\NewEntry{}{\textit{Born in Canada,}}{20 November 1987} % Birthplace and date

\NewEntry{email}{\href{mailto:john@smith.com}{john@smith.com}} % Email address

\NewEntry{website}{\href{http://www.johnsmith.com}{http://www.johnsmith.com}} % Personal website

\NewEntry{phone}{(H) +1 (000) 111 1111\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ (M) +1 (000) 111 1112} % Phone number(s)

\vspace{1em} % Extra white space between the personal information section and goal


\section*{Goal}

\Description{Gain fundamental experience in my area of interest and expertise.}\vspace{2em}


\section*{Work Experience}

\NewEntry{2012--Present}{1\textsuperscript{st} Year Analyst, \textsc{Lehman Brothers}}

\Description{%
  \MarginText{Lehman Brothers}%
  Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a wide array of commodities (ags, oils, precious and base metals), managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes, liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping.
  \newline Reference: John \textsc{McDonald}\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ +1 (000) 111 1111\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \href{mailto:john@lehman.com}{john@lehman.com}}

\NewEntry{2010--2011}{Summer Intern, \textsc{Initech Inc}  --- Chicago}

\Description{%
  \MarginText{Initech Inc}%
  Rated "truly distinctive" for Analytical Skills and Teamwork.
  \newline Reference: Bill \textsc{Lumbergh}\ \ +1 (000) 111 1111\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \href{mailto:bill@initech.com}{bill@initech.com}}

\NewEntry{Feb'14--current}{Technical Service Manager, \textsc{Gilette, PnG}}

\Description{%
  \MarginText{Buy More}%
  Worked in the Nerd Herd and helped to solve computer problems by asking customers to turn their computers off and on again.
  \newline Reference: Big \textsc{Mike}\ \ +1 (000) 111 1111\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \href{mailto:mike@buymore.com}{mike@buymore.com}}

\end{cv}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as in the above screenshot, but everything is accomplished automatically now.