# Columns and enumeration

Tags: formatting

I want to arrange items in the following way.

[image]

Special features observed are

1. Things are arranged in two columns.
2. Enumeration items are arranged in two inner columns nested inside each of the two outer columns, resulting in apparently a total of four columns.
3. (However, if the text is too long to put, then they do not form the inner columns. See item 5-6, 35-42.)
4. [Items switch horizontally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89603/horizontal-enumeration-in-multiple-columns) between the inner columns.

How can I do with LaTeX? (For my purpose, feature number 3 above is not a must.)

Comment: Please (always) supply a complete test document with which people can test their answers.

Comment: Have you seen http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35460/ and especially http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107269/

Comment: cgnieder: thank you for your links. I had already tried to search for them for half an hour before asking this question. (How can you find them?) I think my question need no further answers.

Comment: @HYC I found them because I knew thy existed :) We will probably close your question as a duplicate then.